# Desktop is distorted, launcher in the middle, double image, bad resolution

Tags: nvidia, graphics, display, display-resolution, visual-artifacts

I am very new to Ubuntu. I followed [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pE-Jg5fXak) on replacing Windows with Ubuntu on my crummy laptop. When the installer loaded up there were resolution problems where two versions of the screen were being displayed at once, with an overlap in the middle (almost like a venn diagram). I assumed this was a little glitch and that it would disappear after finishing the installation. As far as I can tell, it didn't. A couple of reboots later, it's still there.

I am running the 64-bit version of 14.04.3 LTS. The laptop has Nvidia graphics (could it be as simple as trying the 32-bit version? I have the specs for 64!)

[image: graphical glitch still in place]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating device drivers?

Go into the dash menu and open **Additional Drivers** and select the latest proprietary driver on the list. It should say something like **NVIDIA Binary Driver.** Afterwards, press <kbd>Apply Changes</kbd> and then reboot.

It should look something like this:

[image: additional drivers dialog]

If you have an Optimus laptop, you might need to install [Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee).

If you can't use the settings menu because of your display issues, you can install proprietary drivers if you manage to get into a shell by typing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

This will install Nvidia's 352.63 driver which is the latest stable one at the time of posting as far as I know (future readers may need to adjust the command. See [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)). More information can be found [here on the Ubuntu Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia).